# Finding elements of a sample space

Tags: statistics

Consider an experiment where student A and B independently toss a coin thrice. Let x_a: be the number of tails observed by Student A and x_b be the number of heads observed by Student B.

a)List elements (x_a, x_b) of the sample space.

Would the answer to a) Be ({HHH, HHT, HTT, TTT} , {TTT, TTH, THH, HHH}) ?

Comment: No since $x_a$ and $x_b$ have to be numbers. i.e, $x_a,x_b\in \{ 0,1,2,3  \}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

An element of the sample space would look like, for example, $(1,3)$ (this would correspond to student A getting $1$ tail and student B getting $3$ heads).